# Работа с датами

Tags: php

Мне нужно добавлять время/дату к предыдущей.

Я сделал так:

```
$f = getdate(strtotime($start_date)); 
$duration = 1000; //любое число в секундах 
$end_date = date('YmdHis O', mktime(
  $f['hours'],
  $f['minutes'],
  $f['seconds'] + $duration,
  $f['mon'],
  $f['mday'],
  $f['year']
));
```

Нельзя ли как-либо упростить или сократить этот код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. дата в PHP хранится в UNIX-формате, т.е. это количество секунд, прошедших с  1 января 1970 года, то достаточно просто прибавить к дате нужное число секунд

```
$f = strtotime($start_date); 
$duration = 1000; //любое число в секундах 
$end_date = $f + $duration;
```

Comment: Как же просто это оказалось :)